# JavaScript - Shuffling Objects inside an object (randomize)

Tags: javascript, json, object, shuffle, random

I need to implement a randomization from JSON result.

The format of the JSON is two objects:

result:

**Question(object)**

```
[Object { id="4c6e9a41470b19_96235904",  more...}, 
 Object { id="4c784e6e928868_58699409",  more...}, 
 Object { id="4c6ecd074662c5_02703822",  more...}, 6 more...]
```

**Topic(object)**

```
[Object { id="3jhf3533279827_23424234",  more...}, 
 Object { id="4634663466cvv5_43235236",  more...}, 
 Object { id="47hf3892735298_08476548",  more...}, 2 more...]
```

I want to randomize the order of the objects inside the question object and the topic objects.

Comment: Those are not objects, those are **arrays** containing objects.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You could use a [Fisher-Yates-Durstenfeld shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle#The_modern_algorithm):

```
var shuffledQuestionArray = shuffle(yourQuestionArray);
var shuffledTopicArray = shuffle(yourTopicArray);

// ...

function shuffle(sourceArray) {
    for (var i = 0; i < sourceArray.length - 1; i++) {
        var j = i + Math.floor(Math.random() * (sourceArray.length - i));

        var temp = sourceArray[j];
        sourceArray[j] = sourceArray[i];
        sourceArray[i] = temp;
    }
    return sourceArray;
}
```

Answer (score 13):

Easiest method (not perfect shuffle, but in some cases may be better):

```
function randomize(a, b) {
    return Math.random() - 0.5;
}

yourQuestionArray.sort(randomize);
yourTopicArray.sort(randomize);
```

or

```
yourQuestionArray.sort(function (a, b) {return Math.random() - 0.5;});
yourTopicArray.sort(function (a, b) {return Math.random() - 0.5;});
```

( http://jsfiddle.net/dJVHs/ )

Comment: For larger arrays this will (probably) be slower than a Fisher-Yates shuffle too. The shuffle will be O(n) whereas using sort will (probably) be O(n log n).

Comment: @LukeH OK, you are right. But this is more beautiful :P

Comment: This is a very clean and elegant solution. Take my upvote...

Answer (score 7):

I found [this post](http://sedition.com/perl/javascript-fy.html) on using the [Fisher-Yates algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) to shuffle an array in JavaScript.  It uses this function:

```
function fisherYates ( myArray ) {
  var i = myArray.length;
  if ( i == 0 ) return false;
  while ( --i ) {
     var j = Math.floor( Math.random() * ( i + 1 ) );
     var tempi = myArray[i];
     var tempj = myArray[j];
     myArray[i] = tempj;
     myArray[j] = tempi;
   }
}
```

Comment: You don't have to make `tempj`

Comment: Thanks, great for my needs !